# Running a groovy script in neo4j shell using gsh gives "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.Binding"

Tags: groovy, neo4j

Running a groovy script in neo4j shell using **gsh** gives "`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.Binding`".

Even a simple script command like `gsh --test`
with the following file in the GSP_PATH fails:

```
test.groovy:
    println "test!"
```

What are the steps to solve this?

Comment: "Even a simple ..." ... what? Fails or works? Please complete the sentence :-)

Answer (score 0):

The groovy dependency is missing:

Just copy the groovy jar into your lib directory

```
cp /Users/mh/Downloads/groovy-2.3.7/embeddable/groovy-all-2.3.7.jar path/to/neo4j-community-2.1.5/lib/
```

Comment: problem stays groovy-all-2.3.7.jar is in the classpath as seen by Neo4jShell.bat, but same binding error remains. Neo version is 2.1.4 and community version on windows (zip distribution)